# Multiprocessing Python not working parallely

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mlp

class Test(mlp.Process):
    def run(self):
        if self.name == "Test-2":
            import time
            time.sleep(4)
        print self.name

jobs = []
for i in range(5):
    m = Test()
    jobs.append(m)
    m.run()
for i in jobs:
    i.join()
```

In the above code, output is always:
    Test-1
    Test-2
    Test-3
    Test-4
    Test-5

And these processes spawn only one after another. Like Test-3 spans only after Test-2 is completed. Shouldn't they happen parallely???

And also, i.join() throws error: AssertionError: can only join a started process

What wrong am I doing???

Thanks...

Comment: If someone correctly answers your problem, please mark that answers as correct by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it. Its colour should then change to green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never started the process. The `run` method is intended for the subclass to implement, which you correctly did, but the `start` method is the one you should call to start the process (and automatically execute `run()` in the other process instance).

In other words, call `m.start()` instead of `m.run()`.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately I don't have 15 points since am new here... so it's not accepting my vote up... :(

Comment: Ohh got it and done... thanks for guiding me... uncharted waters you know... :D